# Dynamic url for a tag in Pug (Jade) template

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I want to dynamically change the URL text. This is the code I am using in my Pug template engine:

```
html
  head
    title=title
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
  body(style={'background-color': color })
    #content 
      .bigquestion=message
      | <div class='questionnumber'>
      a(href=`/question/`+ questionnumber) =questionnumber
      | / 
      =totalnumberofquestions
      | </div>
```

I am getting the following:

```
<div class='questionnumber'><a href="/question/98">question =questionnumber</a>98/ 135</div>
```

I want the output to be something like this:

```
<div class='questionnumber'><a href="/question/98">question 98</a> / 135</div>
```

Is there any way that I can use a dynamic text for the URL in Pug templating engine?

I was able to only find static texts examples only [here](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this section in the documentation.

https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html

```
html
  head
    title=title
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
  body(style={'background-color': color })
    #content 
      .bigquestion=message
      | <div class='questionnumber'>
      a(href=`/question/`+ questionnumber) #{questionnumber}
      | / 
      =totalnumberofquestions
      | </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use interpolation, like `#{questionnumber}` on your variable.